# Fullcalendar slotMinutes won't work

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to display slotMinutes of 15 for my calendar. But it's not working. It works well on this Fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  editable: true,
  slotMinutes: 15,
  selectable: true,
  //header and other values
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,'h:mm tt');
      starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
      var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
      $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
      $('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
      $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
   }
});
```

To access the Fiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/AzmJv/16/... However, it won't work on [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/A6ksz/134/), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are comparing a fiddle of v1 with your v2 fiddle.

In v2 there isn't `slotMinutes`. Instead you should use `slotDuration` ([see the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/)), that should be set to:

```
slotDuration: '00:15:00'
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6ksz/136/).

**EDIT: Add description for each timeslot in vertical axis**

The previous fiddle shows the 15 minute slot, but the vertical axis only has the hour (like 6am, 7am, and so on).

If you want the vertical axis to have all the time slots (6am, 6:15am, 6:30am, 6:45am), you can check the source code of `fullcalendar.js` line 5780 (version 2.1.1) where there is a function called `slatRowHtml`.

In this function, the following condition is used to write the time: `!slotNormal || !minutes`, where:

```
var slotNormal = this.slotDuration.asMinutes() % 15 === 0;
minutes = slotDate.minutes();
```

So, `slotNormal` is always be true (we have set 15 minutes period) and `minutes` will be `0`, `15`, `30` and `45`. Since the condition is negative (`!slotNormal || !minutes`), this means that `!slotNormal` is always `false` and `!minutes` is only true when `minutes = 0`, and this is why only the hours are displayed.

To fix this you have two options, each one with its quirks:

1. Set `slotNormal = '00:15:01'`. With this value `slotNormal` will be false and all slots will have a description. The issue with this is that you are adding a second to each timeslot, which means that, by the time fullcalendar is printing `3pm`, it will be `3:01pm` because of the added seconds. You can [check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/A6ksz/153/).
2. Remove the entire condition from the source code and mantain `slotDuration = '00:15:00'`. This will work but you need to remember to check for the condition each time you update FullCalendar,

Comment: Thank you, and how do I display the intervals. For example, 6:00, 6:15, 6:30, instead of just 6:00, 7:00, 8:00 and so on.

Comment: The vertical text should change with [axisFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/axisFormat/). It should already be displaying the text that you need. I will run some tests and get back to you if I find something useful.

Comment: @Richard Tonata, I've updated the answer in order to display the description of each timeslot.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I will go with the first option. I have implemented it and works flawlessly, thank you for your time and effort...

Answer (score 0):

Please find this code in **`fullcalendar.js`**

```
(h && i ? "" : "<span>" + r(n.format(this.axisFormat)) + "<\/span>")
```

Replace with

```
(h && i ? "<span>"+i+"</span>" : "<span>" + r(n.format(this.axisFormat)) + "<\/span>")
```