# Full Calendar Time interval Should be 1 hour and start from 6:30

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I tried this implementation [Full Calendar Implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/csef79y3/).

```
    $("#available_classes_calendar").fullCalendar({
        header: {
             left   : 'prev,next',
             center : 'title'
            },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        views:{
            agenda:{
                allDaySlot: false,
                minTime: "06:30:00",
                maxTime: "24:00:00",
                slotDuration: "00:60:00"
            }
        }
    });
```

In this all-day column should be start from 6:30am and interval slot should be 1 hour.

So all-days column should look like:

> 6:30 am 7:30 am 8:30 am . . . 11:30 pm

I tried lots of solution but not able to achieve this.

Please let me know if any other info is required to solve this.

Thanks 
[image: Screenshot from @lucasnadalutti fiddle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is the place where you've put your options. It should be

```
$("#available_classes_calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
         left   : 'prev,next',
         center : 'title'
        },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: "06:30:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    slotDuration: "06:00:01"
});
```

Regarding the display of `06:30`, `07:30` and so on, on the vertical axis, you need to set the `slotDuration: "06:30:01"`. Take a look at [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/y9mt92et/2/).

The most important thing to notice is the `01` second on the `slotDuration`. Without this, you won't be able to display half hours.

---

*Explanation as to why you need the "+01" second:*

FullCalendar supports axis with half hours or whatever you want, but you need to do this quirky thing. The reason behind this is in the source code itself (view source for [FullCalendar 2.3.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.js)), from line 5714 to 5719:

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? // if irregular slot duration, or on the hour, then display the time
    '<span>' + // for matchCellWidths
        htmlEscape(slotDate.format(this.axisFormat)) +
    '</span>' :
    ''
```

Now, `$slotNormal` is defined on line 5701 and is:

```
var slotNormal = this.slotDuration.asMinutes() % 15 === 0;
```

So, if you have a 30 minute slot time, the condition will be false and FullCalendar won't display the time. This subject is covered in depth in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25869495/908174).

One additional remark: You're using FullCalendar v1.5.4 which is really old and I advice you to upgrade. If you do upgrade, remember that FullCalendar now relies on [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, from your answer I can understand there has certain limitations in using fullcalendar. I can't get the exact output I need, Though during search i got an patch(https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=951) for fullcalendar through which i guess we can achieve the desired output, but that patch was for 1.5.1 and actually I am using latest FullCalendar with moment.js, but i have updated some old fiddle to explain my problem.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra you can get the desired output. Have you seen [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/y9mt92et/1/)? For some reason Arshaw assumed the time wouldn't be displayed when `slotDuration % 15 === 0`, and so you need to set `slotDuration: "00:30:01"`.

Comment: I have seen the fiddle I need slot duration 1 hour. In this case it will show 6:30..7:00..7:30. But I need 6:30..7:30..and so on

Comment: @PardeepDhingra sorry, I didn't understood that from your question. In that case, you can set `slotDuration: "60:00:01"` and it will work. Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/y9mt92et/2/).

Answer (score 2):

Simply pull out the options that you put inside `views`.

This is your [modified working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csef79y3/2/).

Comment: this fiddle is not showing the desired output still time slots are 7:00am...8:00am and so on.