# I want to change the time axis frequency of the full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to see the rest of the time in the time axis legend, I set the slotDuration at 15 minutes but in the time axis only see per hour, i want to show the axis time like this 9:00am | 9:15am | 9:15am with numbers, sorry for my bad english, I thank you for your help

[image: Cap of the axis timeline]

i am thinking to modify the buildSkeleton function, or add the rest of the time with jquery. but maybe someone of you have another way more easy to do that.

Comment: Already andwered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444252/full-calendar-time-interval-should-be-1-hour-and-start-from-630

Comment: thanks, finally I solved the problem.