# fullcalendar slotDuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i am trying to show the time starting from 9:30 am and ending on 6:30 pm with time intervals of 30 mins in between.. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444252/full-calendar-time-interval-should-be-1-hour-and-start-from-630) should have been enough for me but when i try it the time interval gets removed from my fullcalendar altogether.. 
Here is my code for fullcalendar

```js
 

var dateByColumn = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //weekends: false,
        //selectable: true,
        hiddenDays: [ 0, 6 ],
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',


        viewRender: function(view, $element)
        {
            $element.find('.fc-event-container').each(function() {


                var $this = $(this);
                var now = new Date("2016-09-09T09:30:00+05:00");
                if(!$this.hasClass('fc-helper-container'))
                {

                    //2 : moday, 3:Tue, 4:Wed, 5:Thu, 6:Fri

                    for(var i = 0;i<16;i++)
                    {
                        var thisDate = $(".fc-day-header:nth-child("+dateByColumn+")").attr('data-date');
                        var hours = now.getHours();
                        hours = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
                        var min = (now.getMinutes() == 0)?"00":now.getMinutes();
                        var sec = (now.getSeconds() == 0)?"00":now.getSeconds();
                        var time = hours+":"+min+":"+sec;
                        var id = thisDate+"T"+time;
                        $(this).append('<div class="book" data-date="'+thisDate+'" data-time="'+time+'" id="'+id+'"><a> Book </a></div>');
                        now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 30);
                    }
                    dateByColumn++;
                    if(dateByColumn >= 7){
                        dateByColumn = 2;
                    }


                }


            });



        },

        minTime: '09:30:00',
        maxTime: '17:30:00',
        slotDuration: "00:30:01",
        editable: false ,
        allDaySlot: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: {
            url: 'JSON/events_json.php'
        }



    });
    $('body').on('click','.book',function (){
        var id = this.id;
        var end = new Date(id);
        end = end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + 30);
        var eventData = {
            title: "Taken",
            start: this.id,
            end: end
        };
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true);});});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Full Calendar</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/fullcalendar/lib/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css">

        <script src='http://localhost/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did it, this is just a work around and not the actual solution but it works fine for me..

```js
$('tr.fc-minor').each(function(){ // takes the date-time attr for this class
    var time = $(this).attr('data-time'); // your input string
    var a = time.split(':'); // split it at the colons
    var seconds = a[0]+":"+a[1];

    console.log(seconds);
    $(this).find('.fc-time').html(seconds);
});
```